# Export an org-mode table to pdf/png image

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-table, images

I've started using `org-roam` more often recently, and I use LaTeX a lot in my workflow.

What I want to do is this:

1. Create a table in an org file with some LaTeX math symbols, using the org-mode table handler, e.g.

   ```
    #+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable 
     |-----|-----|
     | A   | B   |
     |-----|-----|
     | $x$ |$\mu$|
     |-----|-----|
   ```
2. Export *just the table* to a `.png` or `.pdf` file in the directory
3. Insert the `.png` or `.pdf` image into the org-file to use as a preview.

At the moment I can do this via `C-c C-e C-l l o` and get a `.pdf`, but I was thinking of something along the lines of a python source block to create a `matplotlib` plot as a `.png`.

Is there something I can do with the `export` tags, or with `#+BEGIN_SCR latex`?

The root cause of this is that I want to use `latex-previews` in org tables, but the previews break the table alignment, like in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18931/24188).